# Why can't I use a JPA repository in more than one controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I am building a web application using Java Spring Boot. I'm trying to use a JPA repository in two different controllers. However, it only works inside one controller and not in the other one.

**MyRepository.java**

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Favorite, Long> { }
```

It works fine in OneController without any problem.

**OneController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OneController {
    @Autowired
    private final MyRepository myRepository;
}
```

However, when I try to also use it in AnotherController, I get the following message: `Variable 'myRepository' might not have been initialized.`

**AnotherController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnotherController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    private final DateUtil dateUtil;

    public AnotherController(DateUtil dateUtil) {
        this.dateUtil = dateUtil;
    }
}
```

What's the problem here? One is RestController and the other is Controller, but that doesn't seem to be an issue.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the confusion. I have omitted a constructor in AnotherController in my original question, so I have added it.

For some reason, after removing a constructor, I no longer see the message `Variable 'myRepository' might not have been initialized.` Without a constructor, everything works fine. Why is it that?

Also, `@Autowired` doesn't seem to be required for repositories, but the service needs it. Without the annotation, the whole page won't work. Why is it the case?

Answer (score 2):

When you're using field autowiring, fields cannot be final. First the instance is created (with `null` values), then the autowired fields get updated. That can't be done if they're final.

Since you're using `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, you can just remove the `@Autowired`. This will make Spring use constructor autowiring; it will find the dependencies when calling the constructor.

Comment: But why does it work in `OneController`?

Comment: Good question, it shouldn't work in either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question as I have omitted other parts that seemed irrelevant, but in fact, it was related to the issue. I have no idea why that's the case though. I have just randomly removed some lines and it just magically worked. :-(

Comment: The extra constructor makes all the difference. This constructor isn't managed by Lombok, that only creates an extra constructor. That means that this constructor must follow all the regular rules - every final field must be initialized exactly once after the constructor finishes. You only set `dateUtil`, and nothing (not even Lombok) sets `myRepository`.

Comment: The `RequiredArgsConstructor` creates a constructor that takes an argument for all required (final) fields. The `myRepository` field is not final, and therefore will not be set by the constructor. That means that it must be autowired separately. Change it to final and you no longer need to annotate it with `@Autowired`, as the created constructor will set it, and this constructor will be autowired by Spring.

Comment: Make `myService` property final as well

Comment: @RobSpoor Thanks a lot for the explanation! You mean that `myService` is not final, thus I should make it final and I would be able to remove `@Autowired`, right? I have done it and it seems to be working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. I see that I typed `myRepository`, but I definitely meant `myService`.

Comment: @RobSpoor Thanks for clarifying! Yeah, it worked, thank you!